# Magento - Adding a new column to sales_flat_quote_item and sales_flat_order_item

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4

I'm working with Magento version 1.4.1.1, and I want to save a value in `sales_flat_quote_item` table (and pass it to `sales_flat_order_item`).

I've found [this tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/adding_a_new_column_to_an_existing_table_in_the_database), but I'm not sure if it's still relevant (to Magento version 1.4.1.1) since it talks about a table called `sales_order`, which I believe is now `sales_flat_order` and looks a bit different.

Should this method still work? If so - Can I use it for `sales_flat_quote_item` and `sales_flat_order_item` and what `entity_type_id` should I put in the commend :

```
`insert into eav_attribute('entity_type_id','attribute_code','attribute_model','backend_model','backend_type','backend_table','frontend_model','frontend_input','frontend_input_renderer','frontend_label','frontend_class','source_model','is_global','is_visible','is_required','is_user_defined','default_value','is_searchable','is_filterable','is_comparable','is_visible_on_front','is_html_allowed_on_front','is_unique','is_used_for_price_rules','is_filterable_in_search','used_in_product_listing','used_for_sort_by','is_configurable','apply_to','position','note','is_visible_in_advanced_search'  )  
values(11, 'my_new_column', null, '', 'static', '', '', 'text', '','',null, '', 1,1,1,0,'',0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,'',0,'',0);`
```

If this is not the way to do that in the new Magento version, how should I do that?

Thanks,
Shani

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Create a new module with own setup class extended from `Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup` or just use it as module setup class in `config.xml`:

   ```
    <global>
        <resources>
            <your_module_setup>
                 <setup>
                     <module>Your_Module</module>
                     <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                 </setup>
            </your_module_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
   ```
2. Use `addAttribute($entity, $attributeCode, $options)` method inside of your setup script, it will automatically add a new column to sales_flat_order tale. The same for other entites.

   ```
   $installer = $this;
   $installer->startSetup();
   $installer->addAttribute(
       'order', 
       'your_attribute_code', 
       array(
           'type' => 'int', /* varchar, text, decimal, datetime */,
           'grid' => false /* or true if you wan't use this attribute on orders grid page */
       )
   );
   $installer->endSetup();
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I said - I want to add the column to sales_flat_quote_item and sales_flat_order_item (item, not sales_flat_order).  Does it still work the same?

Comment: @Shani1351 It works the same, just specify `order_item` and `quote_item` instead of `order` in first argument. `order` was used as an example.

Comment: Thanks Ivan - as a note for future reference, the key point in this answer is to use `Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup`, not the standard `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup`.  The `Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup` method will intercept `addAttribute` for the `order_item` and `quote_item` objects which don't have formal `entity_type_id` values that the standard Setup class looks for.

Comment: thank ivan, there is an typo at  'datetime */,' comma after comment closed  ,

Comment: I have also added a new custom attribute to `order_item` and `quote_item`. How do you set a value and save an order item in code?

Comment: @Guus little late but hope it helps: you just use the Setters/Getters of Magento (camelcased). So if your attribute is called "mycustomattribute" you do $order->setMycustomattribute($value)

Answer (score 4):

important thing to know when adding attributes to orders: you need to add the same attributes to quotes, too (at least in my case this solved all problems)

Comment: @fbtb--do you know if or why this is required in all instances?

Comment: @pcronin every order - before submitted by the customer is stored as an quote so a quote is an order that hasn't been placed yet.