# How to add extra amount field in magento checkout process?

Tags: magento

I've added a checkbox and a delivery date box in shipping method. Now I want to save this information. Moreover, I want the extra amount ($10 in this case) to be added in the total order amount. And display it in checkout process and in admin :s

Please help!

[image: Need to save this]

Answer (score 0):

Well after trying to explain the whole thing in here i decided to just link to some resources

Step 1
**checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method**

http://www.brimllc.com/2010/07/magento-adding-custom-shipping-comments-at-checkout/

Step 2 **Show the extra fee in totals:**

[Magento - How do I add an invoice fee to an order during checkout process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499000/magento-how-do-i-add-an-invoice-fee-to-an-order-during-checkout-process)

Hope this helps,

Greetings