# Magento function to get session subtotal

Tags: php, magento

Hi there i am currently working around a php script that i need to get the current session cart subtotal value.

Here is the code:

```
class AG_Fee_Model_Fee extends Varien_Object{

    public static function getFee(){
        $subtotal = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getSubtotal();
        return $subtotal;
    }
    public static function canApply($address){
        $setFee = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/fee/active');
        if($setFee==1)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that this function always returns me a 0.00 result. So it's not giving me the current subtotal value.

How can I get the subtotal value inside this function, is it possible ?

Comment: It would help to know what context this code is running in, since it's bound to a session. What triggers this getting invoked?

Comment: What do you mean by context ?

Comment: I mean what actually calls this code? Is it called during checkout?

Comment: Yes this code is called during checkout because it adds an extra fee which is added to the grand total.

Comment: Related: [How do I add an invoice fee to an order during checkout process](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4499000/418413)

Comment: I did not see anywhere a function for the subtotal in this post.. Please help!