# How to create a new custom option programmatically before add to cart

Tags: php, magento

I have created an Observer for [checkout_cart_product_add_before](http://markshust.com/2012/08/27/create-checkout_cart_product_add_before-observer-magento) event. I am able to retrieve 2 options called locationTo and locationFrom. I then calculate the distance from each location by geocoding the two addresses and using the Vincenty Great Circle Distance algorithm.

I want to show this value on the cart page, how would i go about displaying this value 
on the cart page?

Is there a way i could create a custom option and set the distance value within the observer and add it to the quote item and then it would be displayed on the cart page, or am i thinking about it wrong? how would i go about doing this.

Comment: `echo $value`? What have you tried? Post your attempt.

Comment: My Requirement is same as yours. did you got any solution @molleman

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'additional_options' field to store your custom option

See [Magento - Quote/order product item attribute based on user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412074/magento-quote-order-product-item-attribute-based-on-user-input/9496266#9496266)

Comment: How to add custom option in  checkout_cart_product_add_after observer did have any idea??