# How to pass our parameters to add to cart page in magento

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

I am new in magento.My product has model type and model version.I want to pass model type and version to add to cart page and take that values in shoping cart page.But i don't get any idea .Any one please help to solve the problem.

Comment: Are you saying that your product extends from the class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`? And you want methods that are available in that class in the shopping cart?

Comment: I think he means passing variables in the url and catch them in the cart to do something with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

1. Create custom option for 'model type' and 'model version' for each product. See [Adding Custom Product Options in Magento](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfZCXjWqrSM)
2. Create a custom module that add these options programmatically to `additional_options` See [Add options to quote item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9496266/1191288)