# How to save additional attributes when purchasing a product?

Tags: magento

I have products in Magento which are heavily customized by the manufacturer (i.e. color) but these attributes do not change the product price. For example you can select white or blue product, but the price is the same. I have 4-5 similar attributes for the product, which customer selects via javascript, and gets a preview right there on the Product view page.

Any idea how to pass these attributes on (to the following steps in the checkout process), so that I can a) show them in the Shopping Cart (under product name) b) get them in the order and admin module (where I need to regenerate preview again, this time for the merchant).

I already have a custom module so if I have to override some Magento code and/or templates that is fine.

Comment: The best way of think of this is that you imagine that I sell a t-shirt and that there needs to be a custom text, or one of pre-selected pictures on it, but the price is the same.

Comment: why do you not use configurable products? and then check the used attributes in the child item and use them for preview? If you don't know what I'm talking about tell me, then I'm look for a few links :)

Comment: Hi Fabian. I already use configurable products, but there are some attributes that you cannot add that way, for example if you have a t-shirt and wish a custom text on it, this text would need to be put as additional_options as described in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could:

1. Create a custom module that add these options programmatically to `additional_options` when your items are added to cart. See [Add options to quote item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9496266/1191288)
2. Create custom option for each product or configurable products. See [Adding Custom Product Options in Magento](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfZCXjWqrSM)