# Magento Add product to cart with on-fly generated product custom option

Tags: php, magento

I want to add a product in cart with custom options which is not defined in product. Actually I have a options which is not exactly related to products but want to See/Link it in cart as well as checkout page.

For ex- There are my various added customers in my account which I want to purchase a same product with different qty. I defined a custom option as "Gift customer" to product, but as "Gift customer" having different values against different login users which I can not fix it.

So I want to add "Gift Customer" programmatically while adding product in cart

Hope you understand my problem.

Comment: anybody have solution on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add custom option to items in your cart you should use

> Add Custom Attribute to item - additional_options
>
> Using Observer - checkout_cart_product_add_after

Take a look @ [Magento - Quote/order product item attribute based on user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412074/magento-quote-order-product-item-attribute-based-on-user-input/9496266#9496266)