# Adding a cost record (attribute) to Magento's tiered price in Admin 1.9

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

Below I have submitted a picture of the section I am looking to modify. I need to add a custom price record to each tiered price. Magento has a record for cost of an item, however, my particular customer needs a way to save a "tiered_cost" for each row. This record will need to be accessible from all transactional emails.

Ideally, my rows would be as follows: "Website", "Customer Group","Qty", "Price", "Quantity Cost","remove" On the transactional email I will then need to display the cost per item. Say the price is 14.86 per unit after 100 and cost is 10.00, If a customer orders 125, I need to display purchased 125 of x unit and your total cost is $1000. Any help would be greatly appreciated
[image]

I understand I have a duplicate question on Magento Stack.  But I need an answer as soon as possible and I will reference answers on each if provided.  Stack just tends to generally have more users and responses. Moderators, please inform me of how I should handle cases where I want more visibility across multiple stack forums.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento - Quote/order product item attribute based on user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412074/magento-quote-order-product-item-attribute-based-on-user-input)

Comment: Great supplement, however does not help me solve the saving of a custom price record.