# Magento associate customer with order after an placed order

Tags: magento

My custom module observes the `sales_order_place_after` event, and creates a customer and associates the customer with the order by setting `customerId` for the order.

**What works?**

- Order is placed
- Customer is created
- The `customerId` is updated in the order database

**What doesn't work?**

- The `customerId` is instantly set back to `NULL` by another script

How can I find out what script updates the `customerId` to `NULL`    again, after my observer is done running?

Comment: hi, have you set customer_is_guest to 0

Comment: @faizanbeg I tested my code from a standalone file, and it works. Just when executed from the event, it will be overriding the `customerId` again to `NULL`. My script to set the `customerId` is: `$order->setCustomerId($customer->getId())->setCustomerIsGuest(0)->setCustomerGroupId(1);`.

Comment: You'll get better response at magento.stackexchange.com however, Magento uses a Finite state machine in the ordering processing steps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine if no other caching/obvious issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412074/magento-quote-order-product-item-attribute-based-on-user-input/9496266#9496266 May help as well.

Comment: Setting break points in your IDE to step through the code as it executes could be helpful.

Comment: @DutA. Thats impossible since no PHP editor I know currently is capable of doing that with a framework like Magento.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - my assumption was that calling the `save` method on the order triggered whatever was listening to the `sales_order_save_before/after` events, one of which was setting the customer ID back to `null`. I worked around this by saving only the attributes I wanted, rather than triggering a save on the entire order:

```
$order
    ->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
    ->setCustomerIsGuest(0)
    ->setCustomerGroupId($customer->getGroupId());

$order->getResource()
    ->saveAttribute($order, 'customer_id'      )
    ->saveAttribute($order, 'customer_is_guest')
    ->saveAttribute($order, 'customer_group_id');
```

This allowed me to successfully associate a customer with the order in Magento EE 1.14.3.10 using the `sales_model_service_quote_submit_success` event.

Comment: Your answer makes sense, as the `save()` function is the only possible cause that changes back the customer. I'm going to try!

Answer (score 0):

You should change event to **sales_model_service_quote_submit_success**

Example Code (Magento 2 Version): **events.xml**

```
<event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_success">
        <observer name="quote_submit_success_observer" instance="Namespace\ModuleName\Observer\GenerateObserver" />
    </event>
```

**GenerateObserver.php**

```
 ...
 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
 {
    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getData('order');

    // Ensure customer is registered
    $this->registerCustomer($order);
    $order->getResource()->save($order);
 }

protected function registerCustomer(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order
) {
    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */

    if ($order->getCustomerId() === null) {
        // Load customer by email, create if not exists.
        try {
            $customerData = $this->customerRepository->get($order->getCustomerEmail());
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            $customerData = $this->orderCustomerManager->create($order->getId());
        }

        $order->setCustomerId($customerData->getId());
    }

    return $this;
}
 ...
```

Comment: I am using Magento 1.9. Tried the event anyways, but same result as before.

Comment: Do you possibly know another solution for Magento 1.9? I can still award the bounty as reward.

Comment: I don't have any sample code M1.9 in local sorry. I can't continue.

Comment: Did you try in Default Magento ??

Comment: What do you mean with default Magento? I tried this on my development install.

Comment: That means, it only one Module that you working on in Default magento version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172946/discussion-between-hoanghieu-and-j-meijer).